# VBS Script to adapt in another language

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a script that works perfectly fine on english-based computers but does not once in another language.

The script gets the Recovery Key for Bitlocker of a Machine and then backs it up into Active Directory.

I've identified that I need to update the "**Numerical Password**" into the value in my corresponding language but this does not change the output of a blank variable NumericalKeyID in the end...

```
Option Explicit
Dim strNumericalKeyID 
Dim strManageBDE,strManageBDE2 
Dim oShell 
Dim StrPath 
Dim StdOut, strCommand 
Dim Result, TPM, strLine 
Dim Flag, NumericalKeyID
Set oShell = CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
'==================================================================================== 
'This section looks for the Bitlocker Key Numerical ID
strManageBDE = "Manage-BDE.exe -protectors -get c:" 'Bitlocker command to gather the ID
Flag = False
Set Result = oShell.Exec(strManageBDE)'sees the results and places it in Result
Set TPM = Result.StdOut    'Sets the variable TPM to the output if the strManageBDe command
While Not TPM.AtEndOfStream 
   strLine = TPM.ReadLine  'Sets strLine 
   If InStr(strLine, "Numerical Password:") Then  ' This section looks for the Numerical Password 
    Flag = True 
   End If 
   If Flag = True Then 
     If InStr(strLine, "ID:") Then  'This section looks for the ID 
      NumericalKeyID = Trim(strLine)' This section trims the empty spaces from the ID {} line 
      NumericalKeyID = Right(NumericalKeyID, Len(NumericalKeyID)-4) 
      Flag = False 'Stops the other lines from being collected 
     End If 
   End If 
Wend
strManageBDE2 = "Manage-BDE.exe -protectors -adbackup C: -ID " & NumericalKeyID 
oShell.Run strManageBDE2, 0, True 'Runs the Manage-bde command to move the numerical ID to AD.
```

I'm sure this is pretty dumb but my script knowledge is quite new.

Thank you a lot ! :)

In English the output of manage-bde:

[image]

Comment: What OS are you on? Does it have to be in VBScript?

Comment: Windows 7. I've tried Powershell but the BitLocker cmdlets are only available in Powershell v3 with Windows 8 and above.

Comment: Could you add the output from Manage-BDE.exe (obfuscate the sensitive bits)? I don't have a machine with Bitlocker enabled handy

Comment: I've added to my original post the English output of the command.

The difference in French is that "Numerical Password" is replaced by "Mot de passe numérique"

Comment: Why not just backup all the keys to AD using Manage-BDE.exe -protectors -adbackup C: you don't have to specify the -ID parameter

Comment: Are you suggesting that I remove this part ?

If Flag = True Then 
     If InStr(strLine, "ID:") Then  'This section looks for the ID 
      NumericalKeyID = Trim(strLine)' This section trims the empty spaces from the ID {} line 
      NumericalKeyID = Right(NumericalKeyID, Len(NumericalKeyID)-4) 
      Flag = False 'Stops the other lines from being collected 
     End If 
   End If

Comment: No, Skip the whole script and just run Manage-BDE.exe -protectors -adbackup C: this will backup all the protectors rather than just an individual one. Do you specifically need to only back up one of the protectors?

Comment: Specifying the ID parameters is mandatory in the command. Windows will not let you type "Manage-BDE.exe -protectors -adbackup C:". It will prompt an error saying you have to specify an ID.

Same for C:, you have to specify a volume letter

Comment: Ah, I was going by the docs 
-adbackup 
Backs up all recovery information for the drive specified to Active Directory Domain Services. To back up only a single recovery key, append the –id parameter and specify the ID of the recovery key to back up.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875513(v=WS.10).aspx#BKMK_protectors

Answer (score 0):

Much as I hate to suggest a solution using regular expressions ([Obligatory XKCD link](http://xkcd.com/1171/))
I think it might be your best option here

Something like this should do the trick

`.*ID:.*{(.*)}.*`

To break it down for you

`.*  - Match any character 
ID: - Match ID:
.*  - Match any character
{   - match {
(   - remember anything between this and the next )
}   - match }
.*  - Match any character`

If you're not familiar with VBScript's support for regular expressions this link is pretty good  [Regular Expression - VBScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)

`Dim myRegExp, myMatches id
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = ".*ID:.*{(.*)}.*"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(subjectString)
id = myMatches(0).SubMatches(0)`

A caveat with this solution

- You might need to tweak the regular expression if the output varies a lot from machine to machine (do you ever have more than one protector?)

If you're new to Regex [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/) is a useful tool for testing/learning

Answer (score 0):

Thank you David.

I only have one protector to backup, and also one drive.

The thing is, as I said, everything works perfectly when the language of the computer is in english but as soons as I have a language that replace the "Numerical Password" with some words with special characters like "é" "ñ" it will not be recognized and the variable will get a blank value.

Maybe it is because vbscript this way does not handle unicode.

To illustrate my sayings, here is a screenshot of the same screen than in my first post, but in french:

[image]